# Translate Authorization code from C# to Python3.x

Tags: c#, python-3.x

Hi can anyone please help me translate this Auth code from C# to Python3.x?
Thanks.

```
private static string GetSignature(string args, string privatekey) 
{ 
    var encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(); 
    byte[] key = encoding.GetBytes(privatekey); 
    var myhmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(key); 
    byte[] hashValue = myhmacsha256.ComputeHash(encoding.GetBytes(args)); 
    string hmac64 = Convert.ToBase64String(hashValue); 
    myhmacsha256.Clear(); 
    return hmac64; 
}
```

Sorry if this look quite simple but I don't know much about C# and this is quite hard to understand this.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, not a code translation service. Try to translate the code yourself first, then come to us when you are stuck, making sure to show us what you have tried and create a [mre].